# How to calculate degrees of freedom?

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom, optimization

### Background

I am trying to run optimizations on a multilink (car-) suspension. That is each link is defined by two points, one on the vehicles body, one on the wheel mount. There are 5 links in total, restricting the wheel mount to 1 DoF (up and down).

### Problem

I do have a working optimizer in pybullet:

[image: double wishbone suspension]

This does work and results in sensible geometries. In the image above it "invented" a [double wishbone suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_wishbone_suspension) from random starting positions. Running multiple second long physic simulations in each optimization step does take fairly long thou.

So I set out to build a simplified, differentiable physics "engine" to speed up this process. Simplified as in there is no physics simulation happening, I only move the wheel around and optimize the error in the linkages.

The problem here is that while this does work to some extent, this does not force any constraints on the DoFs that the wheel has. (Mostly it arrives at solutions where the wheel is free to spin around the red axis in the image above).

I tried to circumvent this by translating and rotating the wheel by miniscule amounts and to measure the (unitless) forces impacted by each individual link for this transformation. Again, this works to some extent but I think that having a measure for the DoFs would work better.

### Question

Is there a way to calculate the DoFs? I am not even sure how such a metric would look, probably the "movability along XYZ + rotatability around XYZ" as floating point number? This would allow me to optimize the suspension geometry to only allow rotations in one dimension.